# Moodle event in local customisation

Tags: php, events, moodle

I'm writing the local custom code for my moodle. When user enroll to a course it shoud to catch the event. But nothing happend

This is my code:

lib.php:

```
<?php 
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

function local_newenrollment_user_enrolled($tbc) {

    echo "I m here";

    return true;
}
```

event.php

```
<?php 
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$handlers = array (
    'user_enrolled' => array (
        'handlerfile'      => '/mod/forum/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'forum_user_enrolled',
        'schedule'         => 'instant',
        'internal'         => 1,
    ),
);
```

version.php

```
<?php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version = 2014012901; // Plugin version.
$plugin->requires = 2013051402; // Moodle version.
$plugin->component = 'local_newenrollment'; // Full name of the plugin (used for diagnostics).
```

Somebody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the function to call as 'forum_user_enrolled', but the function you have created is called 'local_newenrolment_user_enrolled'. You have also stated that the function is in 'mod/forum/lib.php', not in your plugin's lib file.

Comment: Tank you for your help. Changed it to  'handlerfile'      => '/local/newenrollment/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'local_newenrollment_user_enrolled', but still it dosent work...

Comment: You probably need to increase the version number for the changes to take effect and install/upgrade the plugin via site admin -> notifications. Also you probably won't see echo "I m here", if you want to see if its working then use the add_to_log() function and then check the contents of mdl_log.